# WPF DataGrid auto-refresh with ObservableCollection source

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and I can't get my grid to auto-refresh when some property changes.
Only thing I achieved - auto-refresh on element adding.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Model model;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        model = new Model();
        MyGrid.ItemsSource = model.Content;
    }

    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public ObservableCollection<Single> Content;
    private Random r;
    private Action action;
    private static object _syncLock = new object();

    public Model()
    {
        Content = new ObservableCollection<Single>();
        r = new Random(); 
        action = new Action(process);
        action.BeginInvoke(null,null);
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Content, _syncLock);          
    }

    private void process()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Content.Add(new Single { Name = "name" });
            Content[r.Next(0,Content.Count())].Name = "rename" + r.Next(1,100);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

public class Single : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return name; }
        set 
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(Name);
        } 
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should expose Content in Model to a public property and trigger your property changed when it has been changed.

Comment: Toan Vo, where should I trigger it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(Name);
    }
}
```

Had to use

```
RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
```

Simple and stupid..

Comment: Yeah..a lot of fun with it . I know this moment. :P

Answer (score 1):

Make you model variable notifyable and this will work for you.

Try Changing the above code with.

```
    public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model model;

    public Model ModelData
    {
        get { return model; }
        set
        {
            model = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ModelData"));
        }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
            ModelData = new Model();          
        MyGrid.ItemsSource = ModelData.Content;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
public class Model
{
    public ObservableCollection<Single> Content { get; set; }

    private Random r;

    private static object _syncLock = new object();

    public Model()
    {
        Content = new ObservableCollection<Single>();
        Content.Add(new Single { Name = "name" });
        r = new Random();

        // BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Content, _syncLock);
        DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();
        t.Interval = new TimeSpan(2000);
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (Content.Count <= 100)
                Content.Add(new Single { Name = "name" });
            Content[r.Next(0, Content.Count())].Name = "rename" + r.Next(1, 100);

        }));
    }


}
public class Single : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
 <DataGrid Name="MyGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Margin="246,175,0,0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Names" Binding="{Binding Name }" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Changed my code with the code above, but it didn't help.

Comment: Oh dear.. the problem in in my code was in one line: `RaisePropertyChanged(Name);` - had to use `RaisePropertyChanged("Name");` Thank you, Jodha!